# Scanning directory for php files, and include them in the current script

Tags: php, server-side-includes

Would it be a good idea to include extensions for a script this way?

for eg. using [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get a list of php files from a certain directory, and do a `require_once` for each file.

this would run each time the page is generated. would it be bad for performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be bad for two reasons:

1. If someone sticks `evil.php` in your directory it could be included and executed.
2. `glob` is not the most efficient, nor is including via a relative path.

Perhaps look into using [autoloading](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't particularly good practise: you're including files irrespective of whether you need them or not. Nor can you control the order of including/requiring to handle any dependencies between the files. If these are PHP class files, then using an autoloader would be a better option.